# MS Access VBA code in continuous form not working while a subform

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform, continuous-forms

Good afternoon,

I'm running into an issue with some code. Basically I have a subform attached to a question and answer table.

The subform displays the question and the button displays the answer.

This works perfectly when I open the form directly, but it won't work as a sub.

Here is the original code:

```
Set r = Forms![FAQs_Questions].RecordsetClone 'Clone the recordset
r.Bookmark = Forms![FAQs_Questions].Bookmark 'Navigate to the active record
MyAnswer = r!Answer.Value
```

But when it's a subform, I get an error that says "...cannot find the referenced form 'FAQs_Questions'."

So I tried a bunch of things were I'd reference the main page first, below are all of my attempts, each has failed.

```
Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Set r = Forms![FAQs]![FAQs_Questions].RecordsetClone 'Clone the recordset
r.Bookmark = Forms![FAQs_Questions].Bookmark 'Navigate to the active record
MyAnswer = r!Answer.Value


Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Set r = FAQs.FAQs_Questions.Form.RecordsetClone 'Clone the recordset
r.Bookmark = FAQs.FAQs_Questions.Form.Bookmark 'Navigate to the active record
MyAnswer = r!Answer.Value


Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Set r = FAQs_Questions.Form.RecordsetClone 'Clone the recordset
r.Bookmark = FAQs_Questions.Form.Bookmark 'Navigate to the active record
MyAnswer = r!Answer.Value

Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Set r = Forms!FAQs_Questions.Form.RecordsetClone 'Clone the recordset
r.Bookmark = Forms!FAQs_Questions.Form.Bookmark 'Navigate to the active record
MyAnswer = r!Answer.Value


Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Set r = Forms!FAQs_Questions.Form.FAQs_Questions.RecordsetClone 'Clone the recordset
r.Bookmark = Forms!FAQs_Questions.Form.FAQs_Questions.Bookmark 'Navigate to the active record
MyAnswer = r!Answer.Value
```

I'm at a loss. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: It may help to add `Option Explicit` at the very top to make sure you don't have any typos in variable names.

Comment: When do you trigger this code?  Is this from within the sub form? Is this a sub from of the FAQ form?

Comment: In your original code your subform is named "AQs_Questions" (with no F) but in all your other examples it's named "FAQs_Questions", maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: @deluxeinformation thatw as a good catch, but not the issue. That was just an issue with me copy and paste. I fixed it now.

Comment: @BruceWayne I added the explicit and it snagged the "MyAnswer" variable. So I made that a string. 

Same issue though. It works when I open the form directly, but not when it's opened as a subform.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I'm sorry I didn't include that info.

FAQs_Questions is a subform in the FAQs form. 

The button that triggers the code is in the FAQ_Questions subform.

Comment: @HansUp, the Immediate window was news to me! I'm not sure what it means exactly, but it returned "FAQs_Questions"

Comment: @HansUp Holy freaking crap. I can't believe it was that easy. It never even occurred to me to just do an Me. reference lol.

Comment: Cheers mate! I really appreciate the help everyone!

Comment: Even better! The code I posted before was cobbled together from other posts, yours is MUCH simpler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your VBA is code behind the subform button, you can simplify this thing by referencing `RecordsetClone` and `Bookmark` via `Me` (the current form; the one which contains the code).

```vb
Dim r As DAO.Recordset
Set r = Me.RecordsetClone 'Clone the recordset
r.Bookmark = Me.Bookmark 'Navigate to the active record
MyAnswer = r!Answer.Value
```

That approach should work regardless of whether the `Me` form is operating as a subform or if it was opened directly as a top-level form.

However, if you don't absolutely need to go the `RecordsetClone` and `Bookmark` route, just retrieve `Answer.Value` directly from the current row of the form's recordset:

```vb
MyAnswer = Me.Recordset!Answer.Value
```